Suspend mode not working well after update on ubuntu 24.04
I just update my system on ubuntu 24.04. And if i suspend either on wayland or xorg,the system crashes, meaning appear a black screen or nothing appears for wayland, and a frezze image upsidedown appears on xorg,if i turn on from suspend.I tried few times and the system keeps doing that. I think what updated was the firmeware. I have disable the lock screen on suspending meaning i dont need to enter the login password turning on from suspend.
(i tried to lock and unlock screen on suspend an at first it seems to fix it, but with wayland still crashes, and with xorg seems to be working better but still crahes)
Also when i close the laptop the laptop not always suspend
i think it was working well before the updates, but i am not sure
And is anyone having the same issue with suspend mode?
What can i do?
when new updates will be fixing this?
i have a lenovo IdeaPad Flex 5  AMD Ryzen™ 5 5500U with Radeon™ Graphics × 12
(besides the consumptions of energy is much higher on suspend than is on windows 11, that is also happening in manjaro gnome)
(and with wayland autorotation botton doesnt appear on gnome menu like in xorg)

can anyone tell canonical about this so they fix it ?

Does this answer your question? How do I report a bug?

Bug reports are off topic here. Please use the proper method to report a bug.

this is not a bug of an aplication but the system in particular suspend
